# Within my Vue 3 component using Vueify, how do I conditionality render different images?

Tags: html, image, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

My project is using Vue 3, Vuetify, Vite, and it is being hosted on Vercel.

I would like to render a different image (Rank Logo) based on a given value(MMR).

```
<template>
...
<v-img
contain
:src="userinfo.threesRankImage"
/>
...
</template>
<script
...
data: () => ({
userinfo: {
...
threesMMR: 1000,
threesRankImage: this.threesMMRToRankImage(this.userinfo.threesMMR),
...
},
}),
methods: {
threesMMRToRankImage(mmr) {
...
} else if (mmr  < 1100) {
return '@/assets/newRankLogos/0.png';
}
...
</script>
```

And the png image is in the correct location ^

Comment: Please provide formatted code

Answer (score 0):

Yuu can use instead:

```
<v-img
  contain
  :src="threesMMRToRankImage(userinfo.threesMMR)"
/>
```

And remove from `data()`

```
threesRankImage: this.threesMMRToRankImage(this.userinfo.threesMMR),
```

This last line is calling `this.userinfo.threesMMR` which is just declared in the same `data()` method body

Comment: When I do this, the space for the image loads, but the image itself does not render

Comment: There is no details about `threesMMRToRankImage()` implementation. You can inspect the element to see what URL was rendered in `src`. Probably the image path needs some adjustment for the Path logo because if you use `@` this will not be processed properly.